# How to take an object attribute as an input in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

```py
class Heat:
    def __init__(self,name,mass,c,temp1,temp2):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.c = c
        self.temp1 = temp1
        self.temp2 = temp2
        pass #my other code 
obj1 = Heat("water", 10,1,20,30)
```

In the place of the attributes of object, I can directly mention the name, value of mass,etc.
But I want to take it as an input. I am not sure how it's done. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: When you say `input` do you mean things like: `name = input("Enter Name?")` etc?

Comment: Yes ,but not inside the brackets

Comment: Which brackets are you referring to?

Comment: @quamrana the one which has attributes of the objects : Heat("water",10,1,20,20)

Comment: So *do* you mean `input()`? If so, I think @AnnZen has it wrapped up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass inputs into the brackets, and use an `int()` wrapping for each number:

```
class Heat:
    def __init__(self,name,mass,c,temp1,temp2):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.c = c
        self.temp1 = temp1
        self.temp2 = temp2
        pass #my other code 

obj1 = Heat(input(">>> "), int(input(">>> ")),int(input(">>> ")),int(input(">>> ")),int(input(">>> ")))
```

Or you can let the user input the values as a single string with delimiters of `,`:

```
class Heat:
    def __init__(self,name,mass,c,temp1,temp2):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.c = c
        self.temp1 = temp1
        self.temp2 = temp2
        pass #my other code 

name = input("Input name: ")
mass,c,temp1,temp2 = map(int, input("Input as: mass,c,temp1,temp2 >>> ").split(','))

obj1 = Heat(name,mass,c,temp1,temp2)
```

Comment: ,thanks for answering ,but I had thought of that and I was looking for an organised way to do it...

Comment: @VarunSingh Okay, I've added it.

Comment: @VarunSingh  What's an "organized" way to do it?

Comment: @AnnZen ,I am getting this error:    Input name: water
Input as: mass,c,temp1,temp2 >>> 10,1,30,15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc_heat.py", line 30, in <module>
    obj1 = Heat(name,m,c,temp1,temp2)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: @VarunSingh You also need the `name = input("Input name: ")`.

Comment: @VarunSingh What does "organize" mean for you? You can make a function that takes input and returns a Heat. Functions are a good way to organize your code.

Comment: @AnnZen thanks for your help,I got it running